# Is it unprofessional to forward friend's resume to an internship interview you won't attend?

Tags: interviewing, resume, internship

So recently, I got an email inviting me to an interview for a paid internship. The problem is, I just accepted a paid internship recently and have already been working at said place for two weeks. I don't plan to attend this interview. I was wondering if it's polite or okay to decline and hopefully forward/attach my friend's resume who meet the same qualifications?

Answer (score 14):

> I was wondering if it's polite or okay to decline and hopefully
>   forward/attach my friend's resume who meet the same qualifications?

It's very reasonable to politely decline and offer your friend's resume as "someone who might help you".

I'm assuming you have your friend's permission first.

Comment: In fact, very often a recruiter will say "If you're not interested or available, can you recommend anyone who is?"

Comment: It's far more than *reasonable.* Helping your friends and business acquaintances make connections is a valuable skill that pays off manyfold.

Answer (score 2):

Simple. Ask both parties if it's OK.